# How to store and retrieve database connection password encrypted using C#

Tags: c#, encryption

I have searched for an encryption method for storing and retrieving database username and password in web.config, but most of the posts are discussing only about creating a function to encrypt text but not storing as well as retrieving it.

Is there an inbuilt function to encrypt text in C# using a password phrase? I could not find any.

Now I use function given in one of the SO posts for encryption and decryption, but I see some special characters in the encrypted text. If I want to store the encrypted text in web.config the value should be html compliant.

I would be interested in any other approach for both storing and retrieval scenarios.

Comment: you dont want to save any username/password to the web.config.  Why would you want that?

Comment: i store connection string in web.config to connect to the database. instead of storing the db pwd in connection string as plain text i want to store it encrypted

Comment: If you are wanting to protect your credentials from being stolen by a hacker, but your web app can decode them, then a hacker could just decode them herself using your decryption code and decryption password. I am not sure whether this is an increase in security.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741.aspx) to encrypt your data. That data could be decrypted only under current windows user account on this computer.

So, if you create a separate account for you web application pool, only web app would be able to encrypt and decrypt that data.

Comment: thanks alex. the data protection API is bit complex for my level. i thought its a basic scenario in asp.net development. store a pwd encrypted in web.config and retrieve

Answer (score 0):

how about the encrypt/decrypt methods in [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19538/Encrypt-Decrypt-String-using-DES-in-C)

then

```
string conn = Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnString].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: i do have the encrypt/decrypt functions as in the link. but the output of encrypt has special characters like slash etc..so i was afraid if it would decrypt correctly. and i was wondering if there is any better method

Comment: have you tested it to see if it successfully decrypts those characters?